# jsfiddle code not working in regular browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a simple slider for my website and found this example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/AtFeF/79/

From that I created an html file containing all three components from jsfiddle (see below). But when I open this html file in my browser, nothing happens..
Thanks for your advice!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>

#banner_area img {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#banner_area img:first-child {
    display:block;
}
#banner_area > img {
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
}


</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function cycleImages() {
    var images = $('#banner_area img'),
        now = images.filter(':visible'),
        next = now.next().length ? now.next() : images.first(),
        speed = 1000;

    now.fadeOut(speed);
    next.fadeIn(speed);
}

$(function () {
    setInterval(cycleImages, 1400);
});

</script>

</head>

<body>


<div id="banner_area">
    <img src="http://www.wallpaperhi.com/thumbnails/detail/20130309/ocean%20beach%20rocks%20australia%201920x1200%20wallpaper_www.wallpaperhi.com_71.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.star.com.au/star-event-centre/PublishingImages/about-sydney-800x500.jpg" />
    <img src="http://www.ytravelblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Whitsunday-Islands-Queensland-Australia-6.jpg" />
</div>



</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you haven't included jquery file into your html document.

Hence, the code :

```
$(function () {
    setInterval(cycleImages, 1400);
});
```

wont work. Because $ belongs to jQuery.

So you need to include jquery either by

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or download jquery file from jquery.com to your local drive and include with relative path as

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the required javascript files (particularly jQuery).

Add this section to your `<head>` and it should work.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Import/include jquery file in your code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

or the version that you have at fiddle `1.9.1`

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Enclose the script in `onload`, and add it after the jQuery script tag

```
$(window).load(function(){
  // existing code
});
```

You can generally find what you need to add in left sidebar of jsFiddle